# What's the meaning of "cast together"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

While looking for etymology of word Chemistry. I found it's derived from word Kemia or Alchemy which means "***Cast together***". Now I'm struggling to know its meaning/translation. I've looked in the dictionary but it gives different meanings for word "cast" I don't know which one is correct in this context. Moreover, there is no phrasal verb like this.Yet I am of view that it means "to put things together".

Comment: You understand this correctly: the core sense of *cast* is *throw*, often used in the gentler sense of *put*.

Answer (score 1):

> noun
>   1. an object made by shaping molten metal or similar material in a mold. "bronze casts of the sculpture" Google Dictionary

A cast can also be a grouping, a cast of actors, a cast of characters. You can cast (make/show) a shadow. Context is everything.

In Chemistry, I think Stoney B is right, to throw or put or make/form. You can also make a cast by putting material in or under something to make an impression.

Archaeologists make casts of bones or fossils or forensic scientists or police might make an impression or cast of a footprint or tire track.

We wear casts if we break a limb, like a leg.